# Can you email a code review request to an email distribution list

Tags: tfs

I would like to send a code review request from TFS 2013 to an email distribution list rather than a a specific user. I have numerous Outlook email distribution lists already created that I would like to use but can't seem to add them to the list of reviewers in the TFS Code Review request.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can email any work item (code review request, task, user story ...) to any email address.

If you want to assign a review request to multiple reviewers you have to add these reviewers as users in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make sure that the email distraction list was also a security group.

Comment: You mean distribution not distraction :)